# Please Wait message in Ajax

Tags: php, html, ajax

I am little new in `ajax` and `js`. I am trying to send the data to `functions.php?action=signp` but the code says "please wait" and then nothing happens. My code is given below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function signup()
{
    var ufname = document.getElementById("fName").value;
    var ulname = document.getElementById("lName").value;
    var e = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var p1 = document.getElementById("pass1").value;
    var p2 = document.getElementById("pass2").value;
    var status = document.getElementById("statusSignUp");
    if(ufname == "" || ulname == "" || e == "" || p1 == "" || p2 == "")
    {
        status.innerHTML = "Fill out all of the form data";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("signupbtn").style.display = "none";
        status.innerHTML = 'please wait ...';
        var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "functions.php?action=signp");
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true)
            {
                if(ajax.responseText != "signup_success")
                {
                    status.innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
                    document.getElementById("signupbtn").style.display = "block";
                } 
                else
                {
                    window.scrollTo(0,0);
                    document.getElementById("signupform").innerHTML = "Yippieeee";
                }
            }
        }
        //xhttp.open("POST", "functions.php?action=signp", true);
        ajax.send("&fName="+fName+"&lName="+lName+"&email="+email+" pass1="+pass1);
    }
}
</script>
```

Someone please tell me is there anything wrong in the code?

Comment: What does the browser console say? I'm assuming something like ajax is not defined because it's commented out.

Comment: Sir, i have fixed that. I was just checking that xhttp is works or not so commented "var ajax =....". Please Help me with this code

Comment: What does the `ajaxObj()` function do?

Answer (score 0):

I would give you a very easy solution for this. Use jQuery Ajax. Its a very easy library to use.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score -1):

Here how i work with my website, hope i can give you some insight about jquery ajax:
(*all urls and variables are simplified for the sake of clarity*)

```
if(error_flag== 0)//i checked for errors before execute ajax.this is error flag that counts error if any error occurs it will shot its message.
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#registerModal').modal('show');//i show modal to user.In that modal i have spining icon and text that tells them to wait
        //ajax post to register.php
        $.post("register.php",
        $("#registerForm").serialize(),
        function(durum){
            durum = jQuery.parseJSON(durum);
            $("#registerMesaj_id").html(durum.Msj);//if all went succesfull it will say success message.ıf not it will tell user some error
        });
    }else{
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(error_message);
    }
```